# Script goes to bash then back to script a few times before running

Tags: java, bash

I have a binary file (saved as `dpl`) made with [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/). Here is the simple source for that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /Users/Eli/Documents/DPL.jar $@
```

It should just run a JAR with the program arguments. It works fine, except there is a few seconds of delay on startup. I noticed in the title bar of my Terminal (OS X) it switches from `dpl` to `bash` to `dpl` to `bash` for a few times, until finally switching to `java` and actually running the JAR. I don't understand what is going on here.

**Edit:** Additionally, the actual java program seems to be slowed down from this effect.

**Edit2:** I need this to be a binary file so I can use it as a shell interpreter (`#!/usr/bin/dpl`)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you almost certainly want to quote `$@` in that command line.

Comment: I think shc encrypts/obfuscates/etc. the binary it generates. See if you can disable all of that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it as a .sh file and giving it executable permission.

```
chmod +x <your file>.sh
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I want this to be in /usr/bin/ so I can run it as a shell interpreter. To be in /usr/bin/, it needs to be a binary file which is why I used shc to convert it.

Comment: Oh OK, I'll delete my answer then

Comment: Commands in /usr/bin don't _have_ to be binaries.  There are many scripts in that directory on my machine.  Try typing `file /usr/bin/*|grep script`.  And adding `.sh` to a file name has absolutely no effect in Unix and Linux.

Comment: Files in `/usr/bin` don't have to be binaries, but the interpreter specified by a shebang typically does.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able (I don't know how portably though) to use that script itself as a shebang interpreter if the using script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh /usr/bin/dpl

<java or dpl or whatever code>
<java or dpl or whatever code>
<java or dpl or whatever code>
```

Where `/usr/bin/dpl` is just the script from the question.